# R Studio - Merge Files and Write to central file - Duplication Problem

Tags: r, merge

Im new to R & looking for some help on this.

I want to merge all xlsx files in a central folder and write the results to another xlsx file.

Problem I have is this script needs to be ran various time throughout the day and ive just discovered in test that it will fire out the same results.

Is there a way i can clear the write down to file prior to the script running to prevent it just adding to the next line?

My code is;

```
library(openxlsx)

path <- " xxxx"
merge_file_name <- "xxxx"

filenames_list <- list.files(path= path, full.names=TRUE)

All <- lapply(filenames_list,function(filename){
  print(paste("Merging",filename,sep = " "))
  read.xlsx(filename)
})

df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, All)
write.xlsx(df,merge_file_name)
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `write.xlsx` has arguments `startCol` and `startRow` or, alternatively, `xy`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Rui, Thanks for commenting.  In the test I have 10 files with 1 row in each, the merge itself works fine but if i run in 15 mins later again it writes to the file with the same info.  Is there a way to clear down the write file each time before it runs or for the script to recognise the entry is already there and not to add it again?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `write.xlsx(df,merge_file_name, xy = c(1, 1))`? This writes the file starting at the top left corner, simulating it's clearing the file. Another option is `unlink(merge_file_name); write.xlsx(df,merge_file_name)`

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  Ill update it and give it a go.

Comment: Hi, can you help on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677540/r-studio-task-scheduler-installation

Comment: Hey, 1 last issue I have found.When the write file is created it puts dots between the spaces from the original file headers. Is there a way to either, make the dots an underscore or adjust the headers manually but write the merge to the 2nd row down but not overwrite the manually adjusted headers? Amanda

Comment: Are those dots already present in the dataframe? If so, try creating the df with `check.names = FALSE`.